# Lagrange Interpolation how does it work?

Tags: lagrange-interpolation

I am making a program to find a polynomial given a set of data. I understand the summation of the formula. Given the image below can someone explain what the square looking symbol is next to the Li(x)? Can you explain the Li(x) function to me as well?

[Lagrrange Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1mdo.jpg)

Comment: Do you mean the $\Pi$ symbol? That's a product symbol.

Comment: Yes, and ok can you explain how to use Li(x). I don't understand. So for every x value, we are given we calculate Li for all the x values?

Comment: $L_i(x)$ sends $x_i$ to 1 and all other $x_j$ to 0. Thus summing up $y_i L_i(x)$ over $i$ gives an interpolant of all of the $(x_i,y_i)$.

Comment: So for Li(x) we calculate the product of the formula for each j in J but we skip over the i-th element

Comment: That is correct. This is needed so that $L_i(x_i)$ is nonzero.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can understand it via this example on 3 points. This [Desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0redak6svw) is interactive and you can create any interpolation on 3 points with it.

[image]